# Using Windows line endings in Perl6::Form

Tags: windows, perl, line-endings

I'm using Perl6::Form to generate a table and output it to a text file.  No matter what I do, it seems, I can't output Windows line endings.  I've tried `local $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\r\n";`  I've tried appending `\r\n` to my format strings.  No dice.

My code:

```
use English;

local $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = qq{\r\n};

my @column_headings = @{ shift $args->{'data'} };
my @rows            = @{ $args->{'data'} };

my $header_format = join q{|}, (q/{]]]][[[[}/) x scalar @column_headings;
my $field_format  = join q{|}, (q/{]]]]]]]]}/) x scalar @column_headings;

# formatting starts with headers followed by double line
my @format_data = ( $header_format, @column_headings, );
push @format_data, join q{|}, (q/==========/) x scalar @column_headings;
foreach my $row (@rows) {
    push @format_data, ( $field_format, @{$row} );
}
my $text = form @format_data;

my ( $fh, $tempfile ) = File::Temp::tempfile;
$fh->print($text) or croak(qq/Failed to write to tempfile: $OS_ERROR/);
close $fh;
```

Comment: Do you [`use English`](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/pod/perlvar.pod#Predefined_Names)? Otherwise you can only access the output separator through `$\\`.

Comment: Also, the variable name is `$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: @mob Yes, I'm using `English` and `$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`.  Will correct post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp),

> The file returned by File::Temp will have been opened in binary mode
>   if such a mode is available. If that is not correct, use the C
>   function to change the mode of the filehandle.

As such, re-add the :crlf normally present on file handles opened in Windows using the following after the open but before the print.

```
$fh->binmode(':crlf');
```

Comment: Yeah, let the IO system handle it. If you were on a Windows build of Perl, this would happen automatically. But using this will make output CRLF on all systems.

Comment: @ikegami This is a Windows build of Perl, but when I look at my text file in Notepad, everything is on one line.

Comment: Updated the answer with an explanation.